# Kohana style templating in cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3, kohana

I have been using both frameworks for last few months. They both have their highs and lows. Do not wish to start a thread to argue which is better.

Is there any way to implement Kohana style template where you can display one view in other in cakePHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are referred to as elements. Keep in mind a view is specific to a function within a controller. For example, let's say you have a User login. In the Users controller you will see:

```
function login() {
   // code
}
```

Then in the views directory you will have views/users/login.ctp.

But let's say there is a series of links you want to include in all views. It's not wise to manually cut and paste all of them into each view. This is because when there is a change in the links, you have to update every view. So the best way to do it is with an element:

```
views/elements/links.ctp
```

Then in the view, you can simply add:

```
<?php echo $this->element('links'); ?>
```

Now, on the same token, if you simply want to render another view, you can call it with the render function:

```
<?php echo $this->render('/controller_name/method'); ?>
```

So if you want to render the users login view from another view, just add:

```
<?php echo $this->render('/users/login'); ?>
```

This will call `views/users/login.ctp`.

Happy Coding!

Comment: that was really helpful.. i'll see if it helps!